# Docker Compose : connecting python container with postgresql container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker-compose, containers

[image: Python container]

I'm trying to connect my python container which is a web scrape and then upload the data to the postgresql container (database).

This is the error I get from the python container. Everything else runs good except this. I use selenium to scrape some data and then upload it to my database. This works locally, but when I run the docker compose up there's this problem.

[image: Postgresql container]
This is the output from my postgresql container

The question is what is the cause of this and how can I solve it?

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import psycopg2

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

db_params = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "postgres",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "root",

}


class Listing:
    def __init__(self, title, location, image_url):
        self.title = title
        self.location = location
        self.image_url = image_url

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Title: {self.title}, Location: {self.location}, Image Url: {self.image_url}"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

listings = []

# first 500 listings = 20 listings per page * 25 pages
for page in range(1, 25):
        ... (removed some code for better readability)
        # save data in listing instance
        listing = Listing(title, location, image_url)

        listings.append(listing)

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for listing in listings:
        cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO listings(title,location,imageurl) 
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s);
        """, (listing.title, listing.location, listing.image_url))

        conn.commit()

    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on: 
      - backend

  backend:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: server/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on: 
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  python:
    build: 
      context: flatScraper
```

Comment: [I downvoted because of "Images of exeptions"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: The preferred name for the file containing the docker-compose YAML document is [`compose.yaml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/03-compose-file/) (and the [officially recommended extension](](https://yaml.org/faq.html) ) for any file containing a YAML document has been `.yaml` since at least Sept 2006, so please catch up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide a simple solution, if the python code is in a container as your database, it needs to connect not by using localhost, but instead the hostname you created for the database.

Add the `hostname` property to each service you have in the docker-compose file, then in python change the host you're trying to connect to, to the hostname you inserted like this:

```yaml
...
postgres:
    hostname: "database"
...
```

and then in python:

```py
# ...
db_params = {
    "host": "database",
    "database": "postgres",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "root",
}
# ...
```

Also don't paste an *image* of the error next time!

Comment: What about if I'm trying to send a http request from my front-end to my back-end, but the request doesn't go through when I send it through my front-end app, but does when I type in my search-bar the address. I already tried to use the gateway, but it also didn't work and yes I am changing the url I'm sending the request to. As you said to add the host name to every service do I need to specify the port too? So I should just put hostname to every service and then I can use them to basically communicate with other containers?

Comment: yes, use the hostname in every service. make sure the container exposes the right port on your local network by setting the port property. also in the url you can't use the hostname, because your browser doesn't have a dns record for it. all your front end services should be reachable from localhost. hope that my answer was correct and useful

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to `localhost` (i.e. the same container) but your database is running in a different container. You need to connect to the host `database` because that is the name of the container your database is running in.

Note that it is possible to set a different host name for a container but your setup does not do that so the container name is the host name.